# Prevent user from choosing previous date when using Bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to prevent a user from choosing previous dates thus disable previous dates in my datepicker. I am using bootstrap-datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker .

I called the javascript like so

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".mydatepicker" ).datepicker({
       format:'yyyy/mm/dd'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, there isn't any officially supported date picker for Twitter Bootstrap, so you should specify the one you are using. Then, you could show us what you tried, or what is your approach.

Comment: @Sherbrow I changed the question. I did not try the datepicker before I asked the question. Its just that some time ago I used one and was having problems with the default starting date for the datepicker. But the one I got from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker  starts from the current date by default as expected. Silly me, should have tried it first. Can you help me out with the new questoin ?? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validation of the date is not supported (as of now) but the plugin provides events that you can listen to : in this case, the `changeDate` event.

```js
var minDate = new Date(); // Our minimum

$('.someSelector').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() < minDate.valueOf()){

        /* Handle previous date */
        alert('Nope');
        // and eventually reset the date

        /* And this for later versions (just in case) */
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ymp5D/) with a working example.

Answer (score 2):

[My fork](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/) of Stefan's code supports [startDate](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/#startdate) for just such purposes.

Comment: You should add a code example and maybe a link to a working example to answer this question.